# How do I receive API data in chunks in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, stream, node-streams

I have an app deployed on Heroku which contains endpoints and returns a LOT of documents at once. The response is ~ 40 MB and will keep on increasing in the future. Due to the heavy size, the response time is very very high, sometimes more than 5 minutes due to which Heroku suspends the request and I don't get the required data and my app crashes. I need every bit of that data.

On researching for this, I found out about streams and buffers. I just want to read the API data as a readable stream (even though it was not saved as a writable stream), can I do that (How)? Or if I wasn't clear enough, I need all the data but I am happy if I get chunks of data quickly and have to combine it into one piece for the processing.

Comment: [Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22server-side+paging%22+%5Brest%5D) at the concept of "server-side paging".

Comment: What kind of data are you sending through? Is it possible to split the response and send it?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara yes, that is possible.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I think that will work. Thanks!